# SSRS 2008 Group On a Matrix Table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

i am having trouble grouping a certain field in a matrix table under the column level .

i need the field to be grouped instead of shown once on every row as a different entry

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrDyl.jpg

edited.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a group in the Row Groups. Make sure that you have one for your atribute. Than select this group from "Row Groups", go to the "Group Properties" and in the first tab: "General" click "Add" below te Group expression and select your atribute.

Details below:
[image]

Comment: if u check again the next picture , the problem is goruping them on the next level , " Arab Riensurance Company , Arab Union Reinsurance company...." they should be on the same level not 3 different levels.

Comment: Do you have grouped by one or two atributes? I see that you have the ID and the name at the same level. So you should have in group properties this two atributes.

Comment: this is my grouping on the row level : Policy ID , Primary LOB , Market Company name.

Comment: Sorry, but i cannot understand you. Can you post the screen with your row groups and with your group properties? The sama part of your soltuion that i have been posted.

Comment: okay , i edited the main issue above and added a new link for the SSRS grouping and table , i hope this will help you figure out my problem .